# Saving pdf into a user specified directory using FPDF in python

Tags: python, tkinter, fpdf

I am a beginner in python programming. I wrote a code that read an excel worksheet, do some calculations and then save the results as a table in a PDF file. I am using FPDF. The code is as below:

```
def Save_doses(spacing=1):
    try:
        wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("Effective Dose-Stylized.xlsx")  
        A1=float(activity1.get())
        male=[]
        female=[]
        sheet=wb[isotopes1.get()]   
        for i in range(2,44):
            maledose=sheet.cell(row=i,column=2).value
            femaledose=sheet.cell(row=i,column=3).value
            male.append(maledose)
            female.append(femaledose)
        dose_male=A1*np.array(male)
        dose_female=A1*np.array(female)
        Edmale26=sheet.cell(row=44, column=2).value
        Edfemale26=sheet.cell(row=44, column=3).value
        Edmale60=sheet.cell(row=45, column=2).value
        Edfemale60=sheet.cell(row=45, column=3).value
        Ed103=sheet.cell(row=46, column=2).value
        header=[...] % 
        data = [...] % i removed the contents due to large size. 

        pdf = FPDF()
        pdf.set_font("Times", size=12)
        pdf.add_page()

        col_width = pdf.w / 4.5
        row_height = pdf.font_size
        for row in header:
            for item in row:
                pdf.cell(col_width, row_height*spacing,
                         txt=item)
            pdf.ln(row_height*spacing)
        for row in data:
            for item in row:
                pdf.cell(col_width, row_height*spacing,
                         txt=item, border=1, align="C")
            pdf.ln(row_height*spacing)  
        pdf.output('%s , %s.pdf'%(radionuclidename.get(),radiopharmaname.get()))
           
       
    except ValueError:
    #error.config(text="you must enter a number")
        messagebox.showinfo(message='you must enter an initial activity in MBq', icon="error")
        pass
```

This function save the file in the root directory. I want to modify this code such that after pressing the button, a "save as" dialog appear and the user can save the output file in any desired folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This may be helpful : https://pythonguides.com/python-tkinter-messagebox/

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, this is not what i looking for.

Comment: Take a look on [`tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I used the asksaveasfilename after fpdf output and a save as window appeared.  But i don't know to combine the asksaveasfilename with the fpdf such that the asksaveasfilename, save the output file of fpdf. alternatively, i also don't know how to save my desirable contents as a pdf file with asksaveasfilename.

Comment: I think [`tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory) is more appropriate in your case.  If `savepath` is the result of `askdirectory()`, then use `pdf.output(os.path.join(savepath, '%s_%s.pdf'%(radionuclidename.get(),radiopharmaname.get())))`.